# E: The repository does not have a Release file

Tags: linux, debian, updates

I'm on Debian 10, and I installed qbittorrent a while ago. When I try `sudo apt update`, it shows me this:
`E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.`

I removed and purged qbittorrent, but the error remains. It seems that it stops me from updating, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The qbittorrent-team ppa is for Ubuntu based distro, remove it from debian:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable
sudo apt update
```